# Yandex Maps Api открытие балуна по центру метки

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Сейчас при клике на мету, открывается балун "из" то же, точки что и хвостик метки, а мне нужно чтобы он открывался из центра метки вверх

[image: Открытие стандартного балуна]
[image: Метка]
[image: Как нужно]

Это реально ?

Answer (score 1):

Как правильно указали ниже можно добавить опцию hideIconOnBalloonOpen и подобрать размеры balloonOffset:

```
 myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(myMap.getCenter(), {
        iconContent: 'Собственный значок метки',
        balloonContent: 'Это красивая метка'
    }, {
        hideIconOnBalloonOpen: false,
        balloonOffset: [-70, -34],
        preset: 'islands#blackStretchyIcon'
    });
```

Либо это возможно реализовать с помощью макетов https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemark_shape , нужно создать макет метки, который по клику по метке будет раскрываться и изображать, то что вы хотите.

Comment: а вариант с balloonOffset? Для небольшого количества меток можно вручную раздать смещение балуна. https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/Balloon-docpage/#Balloon__param-options.offset

Comment: Да, признаю свою ошибку. Для малого количества меток, отличный вариант!